# Don't you just hate it when

Tags: discussion

…someone deletes a post just as you finish answering it?

[Meaning of "Rooting your device"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56148/meaning-of-rooting-your-device)

Gone.

`</gripe>`

Comment: Yeah...But what can we do about it? **Life is cruel.**

Comment: Not a lot, & I don't imagine my non-question would attract much in the way of upvotes, but I just wanted a little quiet rant ;) apologies… though I shan't delete it until it has some great answers :P

Comment: Wait! I wanna VTC! This question isn't about the site policies that govern the blah blah blah! XD

Comment: Ah, but on the serious side of the field, I have seen some constructive rants that point to some *under-the-skin* annoying behavior. Big example is http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6303/the-secret-to-getting-a-massive-reputation-is

Comment: That is a beautiful rant, rightly righteous… & just as meaningless as mine in the overall scheme of things; we will not change the world ;-)

Comment: It's okay, we can vote to undelete.

Comment: & I see it's back… which now makes this the most pointless rant of all time, I guess. I'll leave it to gather dust on the shelves of posterity, with fading copies of the Times & a collection of old yoghurt pots that may come in handy some day...

Comment: @Tet - Pointless? I don't think so. It probably would not have gotten the needed undelete votes had you not brought this to the community's attention.